# Espaços no input quando escrever algo

Tags: primefaces, java-ee, bootstrap-3

Tenho uma aplicação em Java Web, possuo um input text e gostaria de colocar um botão ou algo do tipo, pois quando digitar algo dentro desse input, se o usuário desejar pode ir clicar nesse botão na qual vai deslocando o texto para direita, como se fosse um tab ou um espaço mesmo, mais queria que fizesse isso no momento que vai clicando no botão. Como posso fazer isso?

Esse é o meu input:

```
 <h:inputText value="#{frameBean.objSvg.valueText1}" autocomplete="off"
                                                     styleClass="form-control" tabindex="0"/>
```

E esse é o meu botão na qual quero que faça essa ação por exemplo:

```
<p:commandLink id="btn_indent"
                  styleClass="btn btn-default" >
                  <i class="fa fa-text-height fa-fw"/>
 </p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Você quer que esse botão seja, efetivamente, uma tecla de `[Tab]` que não troca pro próximo campo do formulário?